# Redirect to view but change URL in Laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect, view

I'm trying to redirect the user after the `create wizard` is complete back to the main page.

If I write in my controller `return view('main')->with('key'=>'data')`, all is fine, but the URL does not change to `localhost:8080` but it stays as 'localhost:8080/wizard/finish`.

If I use `redirect('/')->with(['message' => 'Done.'])` it redirects to the main page, but because there is already a `Route::get('/','Controller')`, the controller is triggered and it returns my default main page with no message.

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                @if (isset($message))
                    <p align="center" style="color: red;"><strong>{{$message}}</strong></p>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
```

EDIT: With a breakpoint in the `MainPageController` (mapped to `/`), I see that this controller is triggered when there is a redirect to the `/` route. Thus, I lose the `$message`, as the `MainPageController` also returns the same view, but with no message.

Comment: you can use `return redirect()->to(main)->wiht('key'=>'data')`;

Comment: use `return redirect()->to('path to main page')`, this may work

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya : this will redirect to `localhostl:8080/main` which is not a valid route mapping;

Comment: @Sagar : this will redirect me to that path, but I will lose the `$message` variable

Comment: @AlexandruAntochi where do you want to redirect?

Comment: you can add that message variable using `with`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
 return redirect('/url')->with('var', 'value');
```

Comment: It does not keep the `$message` as I suspect the `Route::get('/','Controller');` triggers the controller when the redirect happens.

Comment: use $message place of var and its value like:
return redirect('/url')->with($message, 'Done');

Comment: It does not keep the message.

Comment: you can get a message at blade file as

if ( session()->has('message') )
{{ session()->get('message') }}
endif

Answer (score 1):

When you're redirecting, Laravel uses the session to keep the message between requests.

```
return redirect('/')->with('message', 'Done.');
```

So, to display the message change this:

```
@if (isset($message))
    <p align="center" style="color: red;"><strong>{{$message}}</strong></p>
@endif
```

To this:

```
@if (session()->has('message'))
    <p align="center" style="color: red;"><strong>{{ session('message') }}</strong></p>
@endif
```

Comment: With a breakpoint in the `MainPageController` (mapped to `/`), I see that this controller is triggered when there is a redirect to the `/` route. Thus, I lose the `$message`, as the `MainPageController` also returns the same view, but with no message.

Comment: @AlexandruAntochi I've shown you how to get the message, forget about `$message`, it doesn't exist in a new request. Use the session as I've shown.